# how to fetch request which has multiple queries inside using aiopg?

Tags: postgresql, fetchall, aiopg

I use python aiopg package and want to group requests into big one using semicolons.
I tried Cursor.nextset(), but it marked as "Not supported"
It should be something like

```py
Query = '''
    select *
    from product
    where id = 74;

    select id, name
    from product_group
    where name = 'john';
'''

await Cursor.execute(Query)
for x in Cursor.some_fetch_list(): # ???
  print(await x.fetchall())
```